# Facing issue in JMeter while hitting through ASW Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, load-testing, aws-load-balancer-controller

Facing an issue in JMeter while hitting through aws load balancer, I put 10k users with rampup period 10. Nearly getting 67% after that my test was running very slow, and some users are not touched by the load. Getting an error as Connection Time Out Error,  Response code: Non-HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException Response message: Non-HTTP response message: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond.

When I increased the ramp-up period I got fewer errors. My requirement is 10k users hit in per second.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do from JMeter side is adding [DNS Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager), this way you will get confidence that each thread (virtual user) resolves ELB IP address (or host behind the ELB) on its own and doesn't rely on DNS caching on JVM or operating system level

More information: [Disable DNS caching](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420655--Disable-DNS-caching)

If you're not getting errors when the load is less it means that the system under test is overloaded and cannot properly respond to incoming JMeter queries. You need to find the root cause and fix it, it can be:

- incorrect configuration, web applications need to be properly tuned for high loads and the same applies to middleware
- lack of resources. In this case you will either need to provide more powerful instances or consider [horizontal scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Horizontal_or_scale_out)
- inefficient algorithms. Inspect what's going on under the hood using a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools), this way you will be able to see what exactly causes the delays or errors